# Gutenberg Button Border Radius Default

Tags: block-editor, buttons

Is there a way to set the default border-radius for buttons in Gutenberg using a theme?

For example, I would like any time a user adds a button that it defaults to border-radius=10, but still allows them to change it with the slider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress 6.3 now has this option. Here is what you have to insert in `theme.json` :

```
{
    "styles": {
        "blocks": {
            "core/button": {
                "border": {
                    "radius": "10px"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should theoretically work by defining the initial value in theme.json as shown in these examples https://gist.github.com/skorasaurus/d50ea7eb79d664775418492e46cef021 and https://github.com/WordPress/theme-experiments/blob/304e6ef3d561f048c87d9bc27311328ae8197bae/tt1-blocks/theme.json#L276
however, the value is still unset when I tried it out in a theme and it appears they may have disabled it - https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/29210

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned that I tried putting it in theme.json with the same results you found.